# Detect touchstart on body, but not my nav

Tags: jquery, tablet

I have a menu

I want to create a trigger for tablets, where if the user taps anywhere on the screen, it will collapse my subnav. Except, i wnat the user to be able to click anywhere within the nav without triggering `closeMenu();`

I tried:

```
$('#main-container').not('.menu').live('touchstart click', function(){
    closeMenu();
}
```

Where `.menu` looks like:

```
<div id="container">
<ul>
   <li>   
     <div class="menu">
       <a class="menu-links" href="#">Menu List 1</a>
       <ul>
          <li><label><input type="radio" checked="checked" />All</label></li>
          <li><label><input type="checkbox" />Option 1</label></li>
          <li><label><input type="checkbox" />Option 2</label></li>
          <li><label><input type="checkbox" />Option 3</label></li>
       </ul>
     </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      ....more of the same
    </li>
 </ul>
```

There are several instances of `.menu`, that each live in an `<li>`.

What ends up happening, is that it let me click on '.menu-links', but when I click on any Options, it behaves as though I clicked on `#main-container`, and `closeMenu()` gets initiated.

Comment: +1. for a first question it was excellent! just missing the `#main-container` in the HTML.

Comment: Stack Overflow has become an amazing resource. I felt it was important to make sure to position m question correctly and effectively. Thanks for the feedback @gdoron.

Comment: No problem, BTW, did my answer help you or are still having difficulties?